# nodeJs - Cannot connect to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection

I'm working on a little blockChain prototype just to learn it myself and the later work on a bigger project. I've downloaded MongoDB and the **"mongod" command Works when I type it in the CMD**.

However when trying to start my project where the connection is taking place, I'm only getting the error back, that I can't connect to the Mongo DB.

Here's what I got so far:

```
//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", (err) => {
    if(err) 
        return console.log("Cannot connect to DB");
    console.log("Database is Connected   ", err);
    connectionCallback();
});
```

In the MongoDB Compass, I haven't created anything yet. That's why I don't have any DB in the code snippet after the `"mongodb://localhost:27017`.
I've already tried it, while specifying a DB in the connection String.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the **URI** from `mongodb://localhost:27017` to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`. This might work.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try mongodb library in nodejs to create a mongodb client

```
npm install mongodb
```

this will install it and to connect through the nodejs you can use the followig lines of code

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

you can use this line to connect to the db and create a client

`const client = new MongoClient(uri);`

you can also refer here for more details:  [visit here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mongodb://localhost:27017` try to change the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` just like this:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try my below code this worked for me

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

async function mongo_connection() {
  try {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("MongoDB Database Connection Error", err);
      } else {
        console.log("MongoDB Connection Done!!");
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(" ~ file: mongodb.js ~ line 24 ~ e", e);
  }
}

mongo_connection();
```

Here Is my file output SS [Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncnxs.png)